# create vs template and selecting framwork

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

hi Hi I have created a Visual Studio template, But when the user changes the framework version when creating a new project, nothing happens in the program and only uses version 4.7.2
this is my projecttemplate

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>$safeprojectname$</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>$safeprojectname$</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and this is my wpfapp.vstemplate

```
<TemplateData>
    <RequiredFrameworkVersion>4.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
    <MaxFrameworkVersion>4.7.2</MaxFrameworkVersion>
  </TemplateData>
```

if i create a new project and i set framwork to 4.5, The project is created with framework 4.7.2
so how to fix this?

Comment: Can't you use  $targetframeworkversion$ instead of setting <TargetFrameworkVersion>4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion> directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $targetframeworkversion$ instead of 4.7.2 in your project template.